# How do I check mongodb for empty fields

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a react app with no mongoDB and I want to check through a user's collection (Profile) in the database. If any field is an empty string, it should alert the user to complete his/her profile.

How can I get this done please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume we have a MongoDB collection that looks like this:

{
"first_name":"Sally",
"last_name":"McDaniels",
"email":"sally.mcdaniels@emails.com",
"username":"sassysally"
}

There are several scenarios possible.  First, do the fields exist in the collection?  In other words, it seems to me we need to check for two conditions:

1. That an expected field is actually in the document AND
2. That the fields contains a string with a length > 0

My approach to situations like this is to first write the Mongo Query and test it in the console, and then write the Javascript.  Let's start by creating some sample data.

```
use test-db
db.profiles.insert({
   "first_name":"Sally",
   "last_name":"McDaniels",
   "email":"sally.mcdaniels@emails.com",
   "username":"sassysally"
 });

db.profiles.insert({
   "first_name":"",
   "last_name":"",
   "email":"",
   "username":"anonymous-12345"
 });

db.profiles.insert({
   "first_name":"John",
   "email":"",
   "username":"anonymous-678910"
 });

db.profiles.find({})
```

This inserts sample records that we can use to test our query against.

First, I need a generic query that will select all records that either have the fields = "" or that do not exist in the record.

```
db.profiles.find(
  { 
     $or:
       [ 
         { last_name: { $eq: "" } }, 
         { last_name: { $exists: false } } 
       ]
   })
```

This query will return ALL records where last_name is either "" or does not exist in the database.  We repeat this pattern for all fields we want to check.

Finally, we need to constrain the query against a specific user and test against all fields we want confirmed to exist and be non-zero.  In this example I'll constrain it by the _id, but you could do it with whatever unique identifier you have for the logged in user.

```
db.profiles.find({ $and : [
    {"_id" : ObjectId("6381f2c234f9141e153df6f7")},
    { $or:
       [ 
         { first_name: { $eq: "" } }, 
         { first_name: { $exists: false } },
         { last_name: { $eq: "" } }, 
         { last_name: { $exists: false } },
         { email: { $eq: "" } }, 
         { email: { $exists: false } },
         { username: { $eq: "" } }, 
         { username: { $exists: false } },
       ] },
  ]
});
```

If the query returns a record -- then you know that the profile is incomplete.  Now that you have the Mongo Query, in Node.js I would make a function like this:

```
    async function checkProfileComplete(_id) {
        var query =  
        { 
         $and : 
         [
          {"_id" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(_id),
           { $or:
            [ 
             { first_name: { $eq: "" } }, 
             { first_name: { $exists: false } },
             { last_name: { $eq: "" } }, 
             { last_name: { $exists: false } },
             { email: { $eq: "" } }, 
             { email: { $exists: false } },
             { username: { $eq: "" } }, 
             { username: { $exists: false } },
            ]
           },
         ]
        };

        // Query the database and put the result into an array
        var profileCompleteAr = await mongoose.connection.db
          .collection("profiles")
          .find(query).toArray();  

        // Check if the array has anything in it.  If it does,
        // it means the profile has missing or incomplete fields.
        if(profileCompleteAr.length > 0){
          return false;
        } else {
          return true;
        }
    }
```

Please note that the code above is pseudo-code, but this approach should work.